# I don't understand the logic behind my assigning the same variable twice

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

My first time asking a qustion on this site.
I have a simple windows form created in Visual C# 2008 and I am adding the values from two textboxes to two fields in an access 2010 database.  The database is called TestDatabase.accdb and the table is TestTable.  Two variables, FirstName & Address are assigned to the textbox.text values of txt.FirstName and txt.Address.  It seems to me I am also adding the values to these two variables in statement for adding parameters for the OleDBCommand class:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
```

So basically it is working, but I don't understand the logic becuase it seems as though I wouldn't need to use

```
FirstName = txtName.Text;
```

or

```
Address = txtAddress.Text;
```

statements. If I remove the code from the TextChanged events I receive a couple of warnings.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string FirstName;
        private  string Address;

        private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, '@Address')";
            // represents an open connection to a data source.  Is a class
            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\TEMP\\TestDatabase.accdb");
            // represents an SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a data source
            //( takes care of passing queries to the database).  Is a class.
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //IsNullOrEmpty indicates whether the string is null ot an Empty string
            //true if the value parameter is null or an empty string(""); otherwise, false
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
            {
                //has no value
            }
            else
            {
                FirstName = txtName.Text;
            }
        }

        private void txtAddress_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
            {
                //has no value
            }
            else
            {
                Address = txtAddress.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kevin Change these two lines myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
to the following 
`myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);` for starters `your Insert Statement is incorrect too`

Comment: I would suggest changing the private name and address to a auto property. then assign the value of the txtName.Text to the name property and the txtAddress assign that to the Address Property then pass the property to the Insert Command..

Comment: change this as well `catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }` you need to capture the actual exception do some thing like this 
`catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
            }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Kevin!

Just to clarify, you aren't setting the values twice here, per se.

```
    private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
        {
            //has no value
        }
        else
        {
            FirstName = txtName.Text;
        }
    }

    private void txtAddress_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
        {
            //has no value
        }
        else
        {
            Address = txtAddress.Text;
        }
    }
```

You are **setting** the value in the code above.

```
    private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, @Address)";
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\TEMP\\TestDatabase.accdb");
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

And in the code above you are **re-assigning** the values to a *parameter* or, in other words, *parameterizing* the values.  This is a good practice to use and understand as it can help protect you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your sql text

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, '@Address')";
```

you should write

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, @Address)";
```

The global variables Address and FirstName are not really needed unless there is other code that make use of them as form properties available to external code-

Comment: Thanks..that was also causing a minor issue.

Comment: You talk about a couple of warnings. Could you be more specific? The error message and where do you get it I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Trailing ' To Be Removed
String strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable(Name1, Address) VALUES(@FirstName, @Address)";

// Incorrect Parameters To Be Fixed
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he wonders why he has TextChanged methods to fill private variables without using them at all?

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Address;
```

makes use of them, so you can set them, manipulate them, etc.